# how to use only two field for login authentication among various fields in django?

Tags: django

I have made a custom user model with fields like email, age, username, name, password. but whenever I try to make a login interface it needs to use all the fields for authentication other wise gives an error . but I want to do authenticate using only email and password not using all the fields that database have. how can I do that in Django? . when I have tried authenticating using all the fields that database have, login interface works.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instruction in the official documentation, Django has its own authentication system, you can use the builtin User model and extend it with a OneToOne Field.
This should save you a lot of time.
[Django auth system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/)